# Having trouble changing package in Android app using Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, google-play, firebase-authentication

Cannot upload app to Google Play because of wrong package name (I included the keyword 'android' in the package name). I tried changing the package name everywhere but this conflicts with the google-services.json file (I am using Firebase in this app). I tried creating a new app within my Firebase Console with a different package name and then I downloaded and placed the new google-services.json file in the right place. The app still doesn't work (Users cannot authenticate in my app). Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, what is the package name? Where all did you change it? Edit your question to include relevant code

Comment: @MarkKeen I don't think this is a dupe. OP already knows what the problem is, but is having trouble fixing it.

Comment: The full package name is "android.plumberhub.com.plumberhubapp".